# Setting value from modal in html field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have few html fields with common modal attached to each of the field. Code for the same is as follows:

```
<!-- First Element -->
<div class="box box-element ui-draggable">
    <span class="configuration">
        <button id="buttonInput" type="button" onclick="openPopup(this.id)">Add attributes</button>
    </span>
    <div class="preview">Input field</div>
    <div clas="view">
        <input id="inputField">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Second element -->
<div class="box box-element ui-draggable">
    <span class="configuration">
        <button id="buttonTextArea" type="button" onclick="openPopup(this.id)">Add attributes</button>
    </span>
    <div class="preview">Text area</div>
    <div clas="view">
        <textarea id="textAreaField"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="elementIdModal" tabindex=-1 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="elementIdModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content menu-modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="elementIdForm" name="elementIdForm" action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" id="elementValue" placeholder="Value of element">
                    <button id="saveContent" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="addValToElement()">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function openPopup(id){
  $("#elementIdModal").modal('show')
}
function addValToElement(){
  ????
}
</script>
```

Required functionality is as follows:

- On click of button, same popup should open.
- When user add any value on popup and click OK, those selected values should be added to html element inside that button(ie element inside .view class).
- Ex: label, name can be added to #inputField etc.

How can I achieve this functionality without rewriting separate code or creating separate modal for each element?

Comment: 1. I don't see any modals ... what do you mean by that? 2. where is the JS code to see, what you tried so far? 3. what is that with the popup? It is not clear from your code and text.

Comment: I have added modal code in the question above. 2. I am not able to proceed with the function addValToElement(). Not able to understand how I can add attribute value to html element inside .view div and set its value as entered in #elementVal field. 3. by popup here, I am referring to modal. Popup and modal are same thing.

Comment: now I got you. see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

1. get the value from the user input
2. find the existing data
3. append the new date to the existing

Important Knowledge: [jQuery.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function

```
function addValToElement(){
   let currentUserInput = $('#elementValue').val();
   let existingValues = $('#inputField').val();

   $('#inputField').val ( existinValues + ", " + currentUserInput );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Helle. But here problem is #inputField cannot be hard-coded in function...It can be #inputField or #textAreaField based on which button we clicked.

Comment: well ... it should be easy to adapt that, right?